How to run an external python script in Unreal Engine Editor? (Blender -> UE5) (Python Editor Script Plugin)
I have written some python code to import an fbx to UE5. I have the Python Editor Script Plugin enabled in the project. If I run the code in the Unreal Editor python command line it works as intended. How can I run this command externally? My goal is to export an fbx from Blender to the running UE5 Editor.
import unreal

destination_path = "C:\\Repository\\Project\\Game\\"
source_path = r"C:\Source\Project\Game\MyMesh.fbx"
file_name = "MyMesh.fbx"

def ImportToUnreal(destination_path, source_path, file_name):
    # Set Static mesh import options
    static_mesh_import_data = unreal.FbxStaticMeshImportData()
    static_mesh_import_data.combine_meshes = True
    static_mesh_import_data.remove_degenerates = True
    static_mesh_import_data.auto_generate_collision = False
    static_mesh_import_data.build_nanite = True
    static_mesh_import_data.vertex_color_import_option.REPLACE
    static_mesh_import_data.generate_lightmap_u_vs = False


    # Set FBX import options
    options = unreal.FbxImportUI()
    options.import_mesh = True
    options.import_textures = False
    options.import_materials = False
    options.automated_import_should_detect_type = True
    options.static_mesh_import_data = static_mesh_import_data

    tasks = []

    task = unreal.AssetImportTask()
    task.automated = True
    task.destination_path = destination_path
    task.destination_name = str(file_name)
    task.filename = str(source_path) # filename is exported files path
    task.replace_existing = True
    task.save = True
    task.options = options

    tasks.append(task)

    unreal.AssetToolsHelpers.get_asset_tools().import_asset_tasks(tasks)
    return

ImportToUnreal(destination_path, source_path, file_name)


Running this code in blender will just result in this error message:
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text.007", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'unreal' has no attribute 'FbxStaticMeshImportData'


